# Replace fixtures with factory girl in for generated scffold test cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have generated a scaffold which auto generated specs for me,If I want to replace the default fixtures with factories of factory girl what is the procedure
If I replace the Model.create! with FactoryGirl.build(:model)
Test cases fails for

```
GET #index assigns all tag_menus as @tag_menus
DELETE #destroy destroys the requested tag_menu
DELETE #destroy redirects to the tag_menus list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FactoryGirl.build` doesn't persist to the database, you need `FactoryGirl.create`.

Comment: It will create a record in database. How do I delete it automatically after I running a test?

Comment: It will be removed when the test finishes as long as `use_transactional_fixtures` is enabled.